# Giving 10% increment whose salary > $4000 and 5% increment rest of the others

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have a `employee` table with a column `salary`. I'm trying to give 10% increment whose salary > $4000 and 5% increment whose salary <=$4000 at the end of a year. But unfortunately I couldn't write that SQL in a single query.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CASE` expression(will work on most RDBMS):

```
UPDATE employee
SET salary = salary * CASE WHEN salary > 4000 THEN 1.1 ELSE 1.05 END
```

Or specific function like:`IF`(MySQL), `IIF`(SQL Server2012+), `DECODE`(Oracle)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lukasz. If-Else is possible in SQL sql wasn't known to me.